Borrar todo lo que haya antes del primer espacio
Quiero quitar todo lo que haya antes del primer espacio en blanco. Por ejemplo, para este texto
txt <- c("A.A.A.C ROJO VERDE","B.E.Z CASA DOS GATOS")

me tendría que salir
ROJO VERDE
CASA DOS GATOS

He probado con distintas combinaciones de gsub("*\\s(*)","\\1",txt) pero nada.

Acá hay una alternativa de lo que buscas:
txt <- c("A.A.A.C ROJO VERDE", "B.E.Z CASA DOS GATOS")

sub("^[^ ]* ", "", txt)

[1] "ROJO VERDE"     "CASA DOS GATOS"


Te comparto esta solución que me parece una buena alternativa para evitar usar expresiones regulares, la idea es dividir cada palabra, eliminar la primera y volver a reconstruir la cadena:
txt <- c("A.A.A.C ROJO VERDE", "B.E.Z CASA DOS GATOS")
sapply(sapply(strsplit(txt, split = ' '), 
              function(x) x[2:length(x)]), paste, collapse = ' ')

[1] "ROJO VERDE"     "CASA DOS GATOS"


Uno de los sapply sobra. Podés obtener el mismo resultado con una versión un poco reducida, pero con la misma lógica: sapply(strsplit(txt, split = " "), \(x) paste0(x[-1], collapse = " ")).

@JilberUrbina es una muy buena respuesta la opción la que planteas
